# Error in products and sales table with same ProdID column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

Am getting the error Ambiguous column name 'ProdID' just after select because ProdID column is present in both SALES and PRODUCTS. I want to use the one in PRODUCTS.Description column is from SALES table. ProdID is the primary key in PRODUCTS table and foreign key in SALES table How can I do this?

```
 select ProdID, Description
 from PRODUCTS,
      SALES
 where PRODUCTS.ProdID = Sales.ProdID
   and Price Between 10 and 18
```

Comment: You're missing a simple LEFT JOIN where you've placed your ',' between Products and Sales.

Comment: what doe "SALES" do in the query?

Comment: @JonWay Description column is from SALES table. ProdID is the primary key in PRODUCTS table and foreign key in SALES table

Comment: Simply add the alias of the column you want. `SELECT Product.ProdID, Description`... Also, please consider switching to proper ANSI `JOINs`.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: It's good programming practice to _always qualify the columns_ when several tables are involved. E.g. `PRODUCTS.ProdID` instead of just `ProdID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply prefix the column with the table or table alias:

```
SELECT
    P.ProdID
    , S.Description
FROM 
    PRODUCTS AS P
    INNER JOIN SALES AS S ON P.ProdID = S.ProdID
 WHERE 
    Price Between 10 and 18
```

This also uses the ANSI standard way of performing a JOIN. Your syntax (using the WHERE clause) might at any point cease to be supported.

Your syntax would work the same way:

```
select PRODUCTS.ProdID, Description
 from PRODUCTS,
      SALES
 where PRODUCTS.ProdID = Sales.ProdID
   and Price Between 10 and 18
```

But again, you should seriously consider switching to proper JOINs. As you can see, all you do is add the `JOIN` keyword, and move the columns to the `ON` part instead of the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  P.ProdID, 
  S.Description 
  from PRODUCTS P,  SALES  S
  where  P.ProdID = S.ProdID 
  and s.Price Between 10 and 18
```

Comment: could you provide a bit more of context to your answer? code snippets doesn't make it clear for some folks.